# pyspark replace all values in dataframe with another values

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 500 columns in my  pyspark data frame...Some are of string type,some int and some boolean(100 boolean columns ).
Now, all the boolean columns have two distinct levels - Yes and No and I want to convert those into 1/0

For string I have three values- passed, failed and null.
How do I replace those nulls with 0?
fillna(0) works only with integers

```
 c1| c2 |    c3 |c4|c5..... |c500
yes| yes|passed |45....
No | Yes|failed |452....
Yes|No  |None   |32............
```

when I do

```
df.replace(yes,1)
```

I get following error:

```
ValueError: Mixed type replacements are not supported
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For string I have three values- passed, failed and null. How do I replace those nulls with 0? fillna(0) works only with integers

First, import **when** and **lit**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit
```

Assuming your DataFrame has these columns

```
# Reconstructing my DataFrame based on your assumptions
# cols are Columns in the DataFrame
cols = ['name', 'age', 'col_with_string']

# Similarly the values
vals = [
     ('James', 18, 'passed'),
     ('Smith', 15, 'passed'),
     ('Albie', 32, 'failed'),
     ('Stacy', 33, None),
     ('Morgan', 11, None),
     ('Dwight', 12, None),
     ('Steve', 16, 'passed'), 
     ('Shroud', 22, 'passed'),
     ('Faze', 11,'failed'),
     ('Simple', 13, None)
]

# This will create a DataFrame using 'cols' and 'vals'
# spark is an object of SparkSession
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)

# We have the following DataFrame
df.show()

+------+---+---------------+
|  name|age|col_with_string|
+------+---+---------------+
| James| 18|         passed|
| Smith| 15|         passed|
| Albie| 32|         failed|
| Stacy| 33|           null|
|Morgan| 11|           null|
|Dwight| 12|           null|
| Steve| 16|         passed|
|Shroud| 22|         passed|
|  Faze| 11|         failed|
|Simple| 13|           null|
+------+---+---------------+
```

You can use:

- **withColumn()** - To specify the column you want use.
- **isNull()** - A filter that evaluates to **true iff** the attribute evaluates to null
- **lit()** - creates a column for literals
- **when()**, **otherwise()** - is used to check the condition with respect to the column

I can replace the values having null with 0

```
df = df.withColumn('col_with_string', when(df.col_with_string.isNull(), 
lit('0')).otherwise(df.col_with_string))

# We have replaced nulls with a '0'
df.show()

+------+---+---------------+
|  name|age|col_with_string|
+------+---+---------------+
| James| 18|         passed|
| Smith| 15|         passed|
| Albie| 32|         failed|
| Stacy| 33|              0|
|Morgan| 11|              0|
|Dwight| 12|              0|
| Steve| 16|         passed|
|Shroud| 22|         passed|
|  Faze| 11|         failed|
|Simple| 13|              0|
+------+---+---------------+
```

Part 1 of your question: Yes/No boolean values - you mentioned that, there are 100 columns of Boolean's. For this, I generally reconstruct the table with updated values or create a UDF returns 1 or 0 for Yes or No.

I am adding two more columns can_vote and can_lotto to the DataFrame (df)

```
df = df.withColumn("can_vote", col('Age') >= 18)
df = df.withColumn("can_lotto", col('Age') > 16) 

# Updated DataFrame will be
df.show()

+------+---+---------------+--------+---------+
|  name|age|col_with_string|can_vote|can_lotto|
+------+---+---------------+--------+---------+
| James| 18|         passed|    true|     true|
| Smith| 15|         passed|   false|    false|
| Albie| 32|         failed|    true|     true|
| Stacy| 33|              0|    true|     true|
|Morgan| 11|              0|   false|    false|
|Dwight| 12|              0|   false|    false|
| Steve| 16|         passed|   false|    false|
|Shroud| 22|         passed|    true|     true|
|  Faze| 11|         failed|   false|    false|
|Simple| 13|              0|   false|    false|
+------+---+---------------+--------+---------+
```

Assuming you have similar columns to can_vote and can_lotto (boolean values being Yes/No)

You can use the following line of code to fetch the columns in the DataFrame having boolean type

```
col_with_bool = [item[0] for item in df.dtypes if item[1].startswith('boolean')]
```

This returns a list

```
['can_vote', 'can_lotto']
```

You can create a UDF and iterate for each column in this type of list, lit each of the columns using 1 (Yes) or 0 (No).

For reference, refer to the following links

- **isNull()**: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/IsNull.html
- **lit**, **when**: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate you issue with the below data:

```
df_test=pd.DataFrame([['yes','pass',1.2],['No','pass',34],['yes',None,0.4],[0,1,'No'],['No',1,True],['NO','YES',1]])
```

then I just use:

```
df_test.replace('yes',1)
```

Comment: I don't get any error but not theoutput. I am using pyspark

Comment: I think you're not seeing output since theres no `collect()` or `show()`; try above w/ either of those on the end or just do `df2 = df_test.replace('yes', 1)` then `df2.show()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `df.na.fill()` but making the distinction between columns in the arguments of the function fill.

You would have something like :

```py
df_test.na.fill({"value":"","c4":0}).show()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Koalas to do Pandas like operations in spark. However, you need to respect the schema of a give dataframe. Using Koalas you could do the following:

```
df = df.replace('yes','1')
```

Once you replaces all strings to digits you can cast the column to int. If you want to replace certain empty values with NaNs I can recommend doing the following:

```
df = df .replace(['?'], None)
```