# PySpark replace value in several column at once

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, list-comprehension, replaceall

I want to replace a value in a dataframe column with another value and I've to do it for many column (lets say 30/100 columns)

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598366/pyspark-replace-all-values-in-dataframe-with-another-values) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897658/how-do-i-replace-a-string-value-with-a-null-in-pyspark) already.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit, col

df = sc.parallelize([(1, "foo", "val"), (2, "bar", "baz"), (3, "baz", "buz")]).toDF(["x", "y", "z"])
df.show()

# I can replace "baz" with Null separaely in column y and z
def replace(column, value):
    return when(column != value, column).otherwise(lit(None))

df = df.withColumn("y", replace(col("y"), "baz"))\
    .withColumn("z", replace(col("z"), "baz"))
df.show()
```

[image]

I can replace "baz" with Null separaely in column y and z. But I want to do it for all columns - something like list comprehension way like below

```
[replace(df[col], "baz") for col in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are to the tune of 30/100 columns, so let's add a few more columns to the `DataFrame` to generalize it well.

```
# Loading the requisite packages
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
df = sc.parallelize([(1,"foo","val","baz","gun","can","baz","buz","oof"), 
                     (2,"bar","baz","baz","baz","got","pet","stu","got"), 
                     (3,"baz","buz","pun","iam","you","omg","sic","baz")]).toDF(["x","y","z","a","b","c","d","e","f"])
df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|  x|  y|  z|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f| 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|  1|foo|val|baz|gun|can|baz|buz|oof| 
|  2|bar|baz|baz|baz|got|pet|stu|got| 
|  3|baz|buz|pun|iam|you|omg|sic|baz| 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Let's say we want to `replace` `baz` with `Null` in all the columns except in column `x` and `a`. Use `list comprehensions` to choose those columns where `replacement` has to be done.

```
# This contains the list of columns where we apply replace() function
all_column_names = df.columns
print(all_column_names)
    ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
columns_to_remove = ['x','a']
columns_for_replacement = [i for i in all_column_names if i not in columns_to_remove]
print(columns_for_replacement)
    ['y', 'z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Finally, doing the replacement using [`when()`](http://pyspark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html), which actually is a pseudonym for `if` clause.

```
# Doing the replacement on all the requisite columns
for i in columns_for_replacement:
    df = df.withColumn(i,when((col(i)=='baz'),None).otherwise(col(i)))
df.show()
+---+----+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+ 
|  x|   y|   z|  a|   b|  c|   d|  e|   f| 
+---+----+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+ 
|  1| foo| val|baz| gun|can|null|buz| oof| 
|  2| bar|null|baz|null|got| pet|stu| got| 
|  3|null| buz|pun| iam|you| omg|sic|null| 
+---+----+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+
```

There is no need to create a `UDF` and define a function to do the replacement if it can be done with normal `if-else` clause. `UDF`s are in general a costly operation and should be avoided when ever possible.

Answer (score 2):

use a `reduce()` function:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda d, c: d.withColumn(c, replace(col(c), "baz")), [df, 'y', 'z']).show()
#+---+----+----+
#|  x|   y|   z|
#+---+----+----+
#|  1| foo| val|
#|  2| bar|null|
#|  3|null| buz|
#+---+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` and a list comprehension:

```
df = df.select([replace(f.col(column), 'baz').alias(column) if column!='x' else f.col(column)
                for column in df.columns])
df.show()
```

Comment: where did you import this replace function from

Comment: it is defined in the question

Comment: ah okay, there's a replace function in the SQL API, can't believe it's still not been ported to scala/ Python Spark